# Was the final Picard-Shinzon confrontation in Nemesis inspired by the climatic fight in Excalibur (1981)?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, inspiration

In *Nemesis*, Shinzon dies when he attacks Picard with a knife, and Picard pulls loose a strut or some other object and impales Shinzon.  Shinzon forces himself down the shaft of the "spear", and grasps at Picard's throat with his last breath. [Picard-Shinzon showdown at 2:17 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GOumoL4MIQ).

In the 1981 King Arthur film *Excalibur*, Mordred impales his father with a spear. Arthur, mortally wounded, claws his way down the spear, to drive Excalibur into Mordred's chest, slaying him. [Arthur slays Mordred](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1p49F-qcstw).

Though not identical, the two scenes have many similarities.  I've long wondered if there was an intentional nod to the earlier film. Is there any official information to confirm this?

Comment: Yes. It's very clearly a nod to this famous scene, which was itself a nod to a much older (and also famous) artwork called [How Mordred was Slain by Arthur, and How by Him Arthur was Hurt to the Death](http://d.lib.rochester.edu/sites/default/files/imagecache/large/492.jpg)

Comment: Ah, I hadn't known the history of the scene went back that far.  Thanks!

Comment: Fun fact - Patrick Stewart was IN Excalibur.

Comment: This is from the late 1800's; https://kihm7.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/black-21.jpg

Comment: Star Trek: The Horror Movie. What were the writers thinking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but not just to the 1981 movie. This is an example of the literary device [Pulling Yourself Down The Spear](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PullYourselfDownTheSpear). (TVTropes link!) It's somewhat common now, but originated in [*Le Morte d'Arthur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Morte_d%27Arthur) and as Valorum said, was popularized by several famous paintings of [Mordred and King Arthur](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:How_Mordred_was_Slain_by_Arthur.jpg).

[image]
**1880 - Alfred Kappes**

[image]
**1917 - Arthur Rackham**

---

This question was first answered on Movies & TV StackExchange:
[Origin of movie trope where impaled character pulls/pushes blade/spear further into body?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53211/origin-of-movie-trope-where-impaled-character-pulls-pushes-blade-spear-further-i)